# Trigger script Active directory not executed when many fields edited

Tags: triggers, active-directory

I made a trigger who execute a script that update the user in a db when there is an event 5136. The script is executed when I change the username only, or the firstname only, or the surname only. But when I change many fields in the same edit, it doesn't execute.

When I change the firstname and lastname, only the lastname or the firstname is updated. When I change the three fields, sometimes username is updated sometimes nothing.

I tried to set the trigger in `Execute simultaneously if already instance` and `wait in new instance if already instance`(when I edit a field, it create 2 events 5136 with one that add the value and second that delete the value. (x3 for 6 in total when I edit 3 fields).

**EDIT**
It looks like whatever the code event, if this event is added to the journal, it can't trigger all. (for example, if I remove 3 groups of one user, only one remove will be triggered)

**EDIT 2**
Ok I think I found the problem
`$event = get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=5136}  -MaxEvents 1`
The event are created too fast so when the first event is triggered, it picks the last event. But I don't find any solution to how link the trigger with the event. May I do a new post or can someone answer here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to solve my solution, I use the EventLogID to get my event. I need to create my trigger, export, add eventLogID and Channel then import.
In the script powershell, I need to use these two params to get the message.

More details in this page
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/